# Avoid multiple transactions within single execution when updating entities in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

I am working with 2 MongoDB collections, `Recipe`, and `Menu`. A single `Menu` is a combination of `Recipe`. Refer the below code segment for more information

```
@Document
public class Recipe {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String description;

   // getter and setter
}

@Document
public class Menu {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private List<RecipeItem> recipeItem;

   // getter and setter
}

public class RecipeItem {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String description;

   // getter and setter
}
```

`RecipeItem` is just a copy of the `Recipe` object which is referred within the `Menu` collection

When the `Menu` collection is saved, you can add recipes to the menu and therefore a list of `Recipe` objects will also be saved within the `Menu` collection in the name of `RecipeItem`. When any of the `Recipe` is updated, the corresponding `RecipeItem` which is in the `Menu` is also required to be updated. Otherwise, the recipe within the Menu becomes outdated compared to the current `Recipe` after updating. So I have to iterate `Menu` collection which contains the updated `Recipe` by `Id` and needs to update the recipe information within the `Menu` collection.

So the update `Menu` function will initiate multiple transactions within the single execution and therefore we are in a need of a rollback mechanism as well. So I am not very fond of this approach.

I am new to MongoDB and I want to verify whether the current database design of `Menu` and `Recipe` is correct or incorrect? If yes what will be the optimal way of doing it? I know that use a DB ref between collections can be used, but there is a performance impact on it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Menu` document should store a list of `Recipe` s IDs rather than the recipes themselves. Then you can dispense with `RecipeItem` and use `Recipe` directly.

It would seem more sensible that a `Recipe` consists of `RecipeItems` (Apple tart consists of flour, sugar, eggs, apples etc.).

In any case a reference would remove the need to keep two lists in sync.